# Visual interpretation of matrices

Tags: matrices, soft-question, visualization

I'm a student in mechanical engineering and we have algebra classes. The chapter we're currently working on is bilinear algebra. Because of that, we were introduced to many applications involving matrices. I figured out that mathematic had the curious yet very intuitiv chance to be visual. And I must admit that representing a problem using visuals is quite satisfying because, for me, its gives a sense of "motion". And because of that, I wondered the following.

I already know that we can visualize ${3}\times{3}$ matrices with the intersection of 3 planes. I started to wonder if, like vectors using their properties, we could visually represent them as plane intersections.
To make the question a bit more precise, I drew the $3\times3$ matrix, M.

\begin{equation*}
M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & -9 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

### Visualization of M

[image]

I thought that maybe, the intersection of these planes can be a way to "visualize" and for bigger matrices, the idea would be the same with higher dimension plane intersection. But I don't know if it is right.

This question is pure interest for mathematics and culture, but I would be glad to know if we can "view" objects like matrices visually.

Comment: You might want to start with explaining how we visualize $3\times3$ matrices as the intersection of $3$ planes.

Comment: What I think of is a system where you have M, a 3x3 matrix, X and Y, vectors such that X is unknown and for example, Y is the null vector. If MX = Y, you can say that X is the intersection of the plane where the cartesian plane equations are the coefficient of the matrix.

I see the visualisation like that, but I don't know if its right or not to generalize it to higher dimensions.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're saying. What does "the cartesian plane equations are the coefficient of the matrix" mean? (I don't mean to be rude if English is not your first language.)

Comment: Yes, english is not the first language, so yes, I don't know, maybe plane equation would be enough. You can visualize the intersection of 3 planes using a 3x3 matrix, right ?

Comment: Ah. I think you mean if $A$ is a matrix then the three row vectors $\vec{a}_1,\vec{a}_2,\vec{a}_3$ define three plane equations $\vec{a}_1\cdot\vec{x}=0$, $\vec{a}_2\cdot\vec{x}=0$, $\vec{a}_3\cdot\vec{x}=0$ and the solutions to $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ make up the intersection of these three planes. The three planes don't determine $A$ though, because you can scale the row vectors to change $A$ without changing the three planes.

Comment: Yes it is excalty that, I wanted to know if I could visually represent a matrix using intersections of planes, like for Ax = 0.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE

Comment: Thank you, it's indeed quite elegant !